# Running a script inside a transaction T-SQL

Tags: sql, t-sql, transactions, migration

Is it possible to run a script inside a transaction?
Then I could just edit the path to the script and run them in a secure way.

```
:setvar ScriptPath "C:\Script1.sql"
BEGIN TRY
    BEGIN TRANSACTION
        :r $(ScriptPath)
    COMMIT TRANSACTION
    PRINT 'Successfull'
END TRY
BEGIN CATCH
    PRINT 'Error'
    ROLLBACK TRANSACTION
END CATCH
```

But I get the following errors as soon as I try running a script in the transaction:
Incorrect syntax near 'BEGIN'.
Incorrect syntax near 'TRY'.
Incorrect syntax near 'CATCH'.

Comment: Which SQL version?

Comment: Where are you running from? SSMS?

Answer (score 1):

Maybe wrong SQL version - what version are you on?

Could be something wrong in your include script contents.

(Also, make sure SQLCMD mode is enabled.)

The following works (selects 1):

```
:setvar ScriptPath "C:\temp\Script1.sql"
BEGIN TRY
    BEGIN TRANSACTION
         :r $(ScriptPath)
    COMMIT TRANSACTION
    PRINT 'Successfull'
END TRY
BEGIN CATCH
    PRINT 'Error'
    ROLLBACK TRANSACTION
END CATCH
```

File C:\temp\Script1.sql contains "SELECT 1"